# Safely re-size existing BitLocker-encrypted partition without decrypting first

Tags: windows, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker, disk-encryption

I would like to know if it's possible to safely re-size a BitLockered partition without having to decrypt the whole drive. Can I extend the existing partition and, obviously, not revealing encrypted data or having to decrypt first?

The "Shrink" button is enabled in Disk Management, not sure about the extend because the current disk has not any unallocated space. Can other programs extend the BitLockered partition? E.g. MiniTool Partition Wizard doesn't have any options to modify BitLockered partitions at all.

Comment: Is your system configured to encrypt only the used space or the entire disk? If you shrink the partition BitLocker will have to encrypt the entire disk regardless if you disable BitLocker protection or not.

Comment: I used the option to encrypt the entire disk. I have tried on another HDD I had with adjacent unallocated space and Disk Management let's me extend the partition. But everything I find by Googling says to decrypt first. Moreover, other tools, other than Disk Management, don't modify BitLocker (maybe because they don't want to mess with it, rather than being impossible), so I am not sure if it's safe both for data loss and data leak.

Comment: Why do you want to use a tool other than DIsk Management?  Have you tried to shrink the partition with Disk Mnagment? If the option is provided, and the entire disk is encrypted, there is no risk for data leakage

Comment: Is the issue your encryption, or that the partition already fills the available space on the drive? You know you can shrink already, so, thinking through what you know, have you already answered your own question, or can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These operations are supported in disk management, yes. In 3rd party partitioning tools, they are not supported unless the manufacturer explicitly says so (haven't seen any, yet).